# Access Object in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

[image]

As u see, in the Pics, `attributes` and `old` have the same object.  I want to access only `name` in `attributes` but, i end up query `name` in `old` too.

**My Code**

```
            <v-timeline-item
                v-for=" activity in activities"
                :key="activity.id"
            >
                <v-card class="elevation-2">vue
                    <v-card-text>
                        {{ activity.description }}

                        <span
                            v-for="(attr, index) in activity.properties"
                            :key="index"
                        >
                            {{ attr.name }}
                        </span>

                        {{ getMoment(activity.created_at) }}
                    </v-card-text>
                </v-card>
            </v-timeline-item>
```

Thankss....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `properties` is a object then you don't need loop it as a array.
just you can access directly to his properties:

```
<v-timeline-item
  v-for=" activity in activities"
  :key="activity.id"
>
  <v-card class="elevation-2">vue
      <v-card-text>
          {{ activity.description }}

          <span>
              {{ activity.properties.attributes.name }}
          </span>

          {{ getMoment(activity.properties.attributes.created_at) }}
      </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</v-timeline-item>
```

Comment: try with this update, i forgot include `attributes`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are looping over `properties` object.

```
v-for="(attr, index) in activity.properties" :key="index"
```

According to your pic, `properties` object has `attributes` and `old` keys. Looping over it will mean that you want the `name` property displayed for both keys.

Consider changing your code to:-

```html
<span>{{ activity.properties.name }}</span>
```